# Why doesn't my ini file load and save on android using gamemaker studio?

Tags: android, file, storage, ini

```
ini_open(working_directory + "\properties.ini");
global.width = ini_read_real('screen','width',640);
global.height = ini_read_real('screen','height',480);
ini_close();

Here's the ini file:

 [screen]
  width = 1280
 height = 1024
```

**`[screen]
      width = 1280
     height = 1024**

At first when I use gamemaker studio while plugging my android tablet and its developer's option activated,way back in the studio I press play button and after it pretty compiles it and display's my game on my tablet and it seems to be working just fine and everything runs smoothly except when I created the application and send it to my tablet and install it.It really runs but as I played it,the save or load sytem of it's ini file wont work.Is there something or is there any code to actually improve my saving and loading sytem??

And where or what file should an ini file be save??Is it on the assets?raw?values? I'm also asking in behalf of my friend because he is also asking on how to save and load scores using ini fileS and take for example the flappy bird game single scoring system.

Answer (score 0):

`//ini_open(working_directory + "\properties.ini"); 
    ini_open("\properties.ini"); //Instead
    global.width = ini_read_real('screen','width',640);
    global.height = ini_read_real('screen','height',480);
    ini_close();`

i think that is the limitaion on GMS: Android.